# what does (: ${foo%%bar}) mean in unix shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh
unset foo
(: ${foo%%bar}) 2> /dev/null
E1="$?"
```

I know `foo` is a variable, `${foo%%bar}` means remove last `bar` in `$foo`.
But what does `(: )` mean there ?

I'm new to shell, can any one help me? Thanks!

Comment: @anubhava this snippet is part of a function that checks for a sane shell. See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/configure#L17. unset makes sure that foo isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

In combination with the >> redirection operator, has no effect on a pre-existing target file (: >> target_file). If the file did not previously exist, creates it.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `:` means `true`.

Try :

```
: && echo ok; true && echo ok; : || echo ok; true || echo ok
```